# Accessors and Mutators for where clause laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, model, eloquent, accessor

I'm crafting a web application with Laravel but i must use a terrible CMS.

The CMS generates some entries in the Database like "info10", "info20", etc ...

So imagine this table "Pancakes" :

```
id | info1 | info25
```

`Info1` represents the **price** of the pancake and `Info25` represents the **quantity**.

With accessors and mutators i can use `$pancake->price` and `$pancake->quantity` to set and get datas, but how i can perform a query like :

`Pancake::where('price', 25)->count()` than `Pancake::where('info1', 25)->count()`

Answer (score 2):

**It is possible to achieve with this package** https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Mappable

---

You can use scopes in the same manner:

```
public function scopePriceWhere($query, $price, $operator = '=', $bool = 'and')
{
    $query->where('info1', $operator, $price, $bool);
}

// then
Pancake::priceWhere(25); // where('info1', 25);
Pancake::priceWhere(25, '>'); // where('info1', '>', 25);
Pancake::priceWhere(25, '=', 'or'); // orWhere('info1', 25);
```

Don't use method `scopeWherePrice` since `wherePrice` is dynamic call that would result in `WHERE price = ...`.

Comment: Yeah i thinked about this, but it's not the best solution, maybe it's possible to hook strings params passed in the where clause, orderby, etc .. to convert with the right entry.

Comment: No generic method, you would have to create your own implementations of this. Off the top of my head I would suggest hooking on the `get` method and translate `wheres`,`orders`, maybe `columns` properties of the `Query\Builder`.

Comment: for the posterity - I created a package some time ago that allows doing what OP needed -linked in the answer above.